# note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'int *'

Tags: c, struct, types

Here's the code, and this will output the correct answer.

```c
#define MAXSIZE 100

typedef struct {
    int ISBN[13];
}Book;

int main() {
    Book BookList;

    strcpy(BookList.ISBN, "9780133432398");

    printf("ISBN of the book: %s\n", BookList.ISBN);
    return 0;
}
```

And also, gcc said there's a warning:

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
```

So, I change `BookList.ISBN` like this: `BookList.ISBN = "9780133432398";`

But then gcc output this error:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
```

Just can't figure this out...

Comment: change `int ISBN[13];` to `char ISBN[14];` instead.

Comment: @Blaze What keeps you from turning that into an answer? With a little explanation it could even be an upvotable one.

Comment: @Yunnosch usually when I try to answer questions like that, it gets closed as a duplicate halfway through writing my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `strcpy()` is not the problem (rather, the correct thing to do), check the types, that's what the compiler is complaining about.

The `ISBN` variable in an array of `int`s, when, it should really be an array of `char`s.

That said, for a `char` array to be qualified as a *string*, it needs to be terminated by a null character. To hold that null character, you need to have a space for another `char`, over and above the actual content.

So, to hold a 13-character input, the array should be of length 14, at least.

You need to change

```
typedef struct {
    int ISBN[13];
}Book;
```

to

```
#define BNSIZE 14            // easy configuration
typedef struct {
    char ISBN[BNSIZE];
}Book;
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could change your ISBN to be a `char[]` as others suggest, I find it curious to use a string to hold a number.  Instead, I'd go for an unsigned integral type that can hold enough digits to fit a 13 digit ISBN.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
    uint_least64_t ISBN;
}Book;

int main() {
    Book BookList = {.ISBN=9780133432398};

    printf("ISBN of the book: %" PRIuLEAST64 "\n", BookList.ISBN);
    return 0;
}
```